# How to decode escaped file names in git-log?

Tags: git

I came across a repo with a file like this: `til/LINQサンプル.cs/LINQサンプル.cs/Program.cs`, which was encoded in git-log as `"LINQ\343\202\265\343\203\263\343\203\227\343\203\253.cs/LINQ\343\202\265\343\203\263\343\203\227\343\203\253.cs/Program.cs"`

**What encoding does Git use for file names with non-ASCII characters?**

What I already tried

- using different `--encoding` param values
- reading [git-log docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---encodingltencodinggt)
- converting unicode text into bytes:

  - Text (4 glyphs): サンプル
  - Encoded in log (12 numbers): \343\202\265\343\203\263\343\203\227\343\203\253
  - Text as bytes (12 bytes): 227 130 181 227 131 179 227 131 151 227 131 171

Comment: What do you mean by "encoded in git-log"? What command are you running to view the filename? For example `git log --stat` will show `LINQサンプル.cs`.

Comment: Try `git config core.quotepath false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What encoding does Git use for file names with non-ASCII characters?

tl;dr. Git stores whatever bytes the filesystem does. In your case, `\343\202\265` is octal (base 8). Converting to hex gives `e382b5`. That's the UTF-8 encoding for サ. `git-log`, by default, will interpret filenames as UTF-8.

---

Git stores filenames in tree objects, akin to a directory. You can see the top level tree object for any commit by adding `^{tree}`. `git cat-file -p HEAD^{tree}` shows the top level tree object for your current checkout.

For example, if we have the file `til/LINQサンプル.cs` we would see...

```
git cat-file -p HEAD^{tree}
040000 tree 4ef35381184b94ea9e9114a9ab37a9ed2061f598    til
```

This says til is a tree object (directory) with the ID 4ef35381184b94ea9e9114a9ab37a9ed2061f598. If we examine that tree object...

```
$ git cat-file -p 4ef35381184b94ea9e9114a9ab37a9ed2061f598
100644 blob e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391    LINQサンプル.cs
```

That says til/ contains the file LINQサンプル.cs with permissions 0644 stored in the blob object e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391.

If we look at that tree object, we see...

```
100644 LINQ\343\202\265\343\203\263\343\203\227\343\203\253.cs
```

Which is UTF-8 encoding for LINQサンプル.cs.

Comment: How embarrassing I didn't spot the octals :) @Schwern, thank you lots!